# how to display single record in tabular form?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms

I want to display single record one by one when button press in tabular form

how to do this in oracle forms?

Comment: As is, it's a really broad question. Search something, try some code and then, if you have an issue with your code, post a more specific question.

Comment: A tabular form is here to display many rows at a time, not one-by-one. Why would you want to fetch them that way?

Comment: @Littlefoot i want to display single record when press button single forward and all records when press button double forward

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use Forms built-in capabilities and spend time and energy on something else.

---

> i want to display single record when press button single forward and all records when press button double forward

I presume that those buttons ("single" and "double forward") are custom-made buttons (i.e. you created them).

If so, "Double forward" is simple - put `EXECUTE_QUERY` into its `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger (assuming that this is a data block, based on a table).

"Single forward" isn't that simple as you can't *execute query*, so you have to write some code. For example, you could "prepare" result data set into another table, specifying the row number so that you could later use it:

```
insert into temp_table (rn, deptno, dname, loc)
  select rownum, deptno, dname, loc
  from dept
  where ...
```

`WHERE` clause is kind of tricky because user can enter search criteria. How to know it? Use `GET_BLOCK_PROPERTY`. As it brings scent of *dynamic SQL*, you'd have to compose the `INSERT` statement - consider creating a stored procedure which utilizes `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` (or, alternatively, see if `FORMS_DDL` can be used).

As many users can use the same form simultaneously, that "temp table" should be a *global temporary table* or - if not - you'd have to save user information as well; otherwise, you'll create a chaos.

Suppose data is now prepared. In a form, you'd have to create a parameter (or a global variable) which holds current "row number" (rn) value. "Single forward" button's trigger would then

```
last_record;
create_record;

select deptno, dname, loc
  into :blk.deptno, :blk.dname, :blk.loc
  from temp_table where rn = :parameter.rn;

-- prepare the next row
:parameter.rn := :parameter.rn + 1;
```

OK, now you have your data, and new problems arrive. As it is a data block, inserting values into it in that manner presumes that you inserted brand new set of information, and Forms will treat it like that. So, if you try to save it, you'll get a unique key violation (which is OK) or duplicate data (which is bad).

It means that "data block" should, actually, be a "control block", which isn't related to a table. Furthermore, it means that "Double forward" can't work the way I described, but by modifying "Single forward" button's code (don't fetch row-by-row, but all of them at once).

If it is a control block, now you have to find a way to store modified values as well as newly added records, so you'd have to create your own `ON-INSERT`, `ON-UPDATE`, etc. triggers.

---

Shortly, I don't think that what you want is a simple task. Did I already say that you shouldn't do it in the first place? Well, I still think so.

Hopefully, someone else will have a better, simpler suggestion.